# ListBox UI not changing when item is added to ObservableCollection <string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, listview

I have simple program like this:

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> Client= new  ObservableCollection<string>();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Client.Add("Item1");

            Client.CollectionChanged += Clients_CollectionChanged; ;


            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(form_m = new Mainwindow());
            form_m.Close();

        }


        static void Clients_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            form_m.Program_console_1("Collectionchanged: " + e.NewItems.Count);

        }
        static void display_socket() {
            try {

                form_m.listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(Client, null);


            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                form_m.Program_console_1("Display Binding Error: "+e.ToString());

            }


        }

        public static void Item_add_btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Socket sock = null;
            form_m.Program_console_1("New Socket Added" + e.ToString());
            clients.Add("Third Socket",sock);
            Client.Add("Item2");
        }
```

I have created a windows form using the class form_m. When initialized a Listbox- listbox1 is created. I am trying to bind listbox1 to a collection such that when the collection is changed (item added or removed) listbox1 is changed. I have been searching this forum for a week now but I still can't get this to work.

For testing purpose I am using a simple ObservableCollection. When the form is initiated. Listbox shows Item1. When I add a new item using Item_add_btn_Click method. I expect Listbox to show Item1 and Item2 which does  not happen.

If I replace ObservableCollection with BindingList, It works like a fine. Item2 is updated in Listbox as soon as Item_add_btn_Click is called.

Why does this happen?

Comment: ObservableCollection is for WPF, in Winforms you should be using BindingList.

Comment: So you mean the whole approach to use ObservableCollection to automatically update Listbox is incorrect?

Comment: Yes. BindingList was specifically designed for winforms. ObservableCollection was designed for WPF.

Comment: In that case, how can we use a Dictionary to bind to listbox and update listbox when a  new item is added to Dictionary ?

Comment: That is a different question and your code doesn't show any use of a dictionary. Your code has an `ObservableCollection<string>`, you would replace that with `BindingList<string>`.

Comment: @user2288650 It's a couple of days that you are asking similar questions about updating a `ListBox` using a data source like dictionary, list, observable collection and so on. Please read the linked post and after that if you still have a specific question, post a specific question about a specific problem which is not described in the linked post.